# Get accelerometer values from BNO055 using adafruit's Unified Sensor Library

Tags: sensors, adafruit, bno055

If I understand correctly using the [`Adafruit_Sensor`](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Sensor) one can extract information from the sensor specific information. These sensors are currently mentioned in the `README`. I am using the BNO055 for two things:

1. Orientation values (Heading, pitch, roll)
2. Linear Acceleration values

My code is similar to the Example mentioned [Adafruit_BNO055's bunny](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BNO055/blob/master/examples/bunny/bunny.ino)

#### Code

I tried the following in my `loop()`

```cpp
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  sensors_event_t event;
  bno.getEvent(&event);

  Serial.print(F("Orientation: "));
  Serial.print((float)event.orientation.x);
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.print((float)event.orientation.y);
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.print((float)event.orientation.z);
  Serial.println(F(""));

  Serial.print(F("Acceleration: "));
  Serial.print((float)event.acceleration.x);
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.print((float)event.acceleration.y);
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.print((float)event.acceleration.z);
  Serial.println(F(""));

  delay(BNO055_SAMPLERATE_DELAY_MS);
}
```

Created `sensors_event_t event` and used the `orientation` and `acceleration` parameters to obtain the orientation and acceleration values in x, y, z directions.

#### output

The orientation and accleration values are the same:

```cpp
Orientation: 105.50 -20.56 -101.00
Acceleration: 105.50 -20.56 -101.00
Orientation: 97.81 -14.69 -119.56
Acceleration: 97.81 -14.69 -119.56
Orientation: 93.81 -10.94 -125.56
Acceleration: 93.81 -10.94 -125.56
Orientation: 94.44 -12.25 -122.56
```

I tried adding another event `event1` in the `loop()` but I still get the same results

```cpp
sensors_event_t event;
  bno.getEvent(&event);

  Serial.print(F("Orientation: "));
  Serial.print((float)event.orientation.x);
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.print((float)event.orientation.y);
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.print((float)event.orientation.z);
  Serial.println(F(""));

  sensors_event_t event1;
  bno.getEvent(&event1);
  Serial.print(F("Acceleration: "));
  Serial.print((float)event1.acceleration.x);
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.print((float)event1.acceleration.y);
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.print((float)event1.acceleration.z);
  Serial.println(F(""));

  delay(BNO055_SAMPLERATE_DELAY_MS);
```

Can't the BNO055 along with the Adafruit_Sensor library not provide the acceleration and orientation values as events or is the library used only to obtain orientation values from the BNO055?

Comment: does I2C scanner find it?

Comment: @Juraj yes I get addresses `0x28` and `0x68`. Also I have an RTC connected to the I2C bus.

Comment: according to bno's datasheet `0x28` is the secondary address and hence it is detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Findings

If I use the same `sensors_event_t` in the code and use `event.acceleration` and `event.orientation` within the `loop()` and they provide me exactly the same values. I in fact get the same values for heading, pitch, roll and acceleration in x, y, z direction.

```
sensors_event_t event;
  bno.getEvent(&event);

  Serial.print(F("Orientation: "));
  Serial.print((float)event.orientation.heading);
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.print((float)event.orientation.pitch);
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.print((float)event.orientation.roll);
  Serial.println(F(""));
 Serial.print((float)event.acceleration.x); // same as roll
 Serial.println(F(""));
 Serial.print((float)event.acceleration.y); // same as pitch
 Serial.println(F(""));
 Serial.print((float)event.acceleration.z); // same as heading
 Serial.println(F(""));
```

### Sensor

I have a **Blue Dot** BNO055 sensor and it has marking on it for X, Y, Z directions as follows:
[image: Orientation on Sensor]

I crossed checked with the logic of [Euler Angles from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#/media/File:Yaw_Axis_Corrected.svg)

If i rotate along the x Axis, I do in fact get roll (0 to 360) and so on.

### Inference

The `Adafruit_Sensor` library provides only orientation values when used with BNO055 and Linear acceleration values need to be called separately using the **Adafruit_BNO055**.

#### code for Linear Acceleration and orientation

```
  sensors_event_t event;
  bno.getEvent(&event);

  Serial.print(F("Orientation: "));
  Serial.print((float)event.orientation.heading);
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.print((float)event.orientation.pitch);
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.print((float)event.orientation.roll);
  Serial.println(F(""));
//  Serial.print((float)event.acceleration.x); // same as roll
//  Serial.println(F(""));
//  Serial.print((float)event.acceleration.y); // same as pitch
//  Serial.println(F(""));
//  Serial.print((float)event.acceleration.z); // same as heading
//  Serial.println(F(""));

  imu::Vector<3> li_ac = bno.getVector(Adafruit_BNO055::VECTOR_ACCELEROMETER);
  Serial.print(F("Li. Acc.: "));
  Serial.print((float)li_ac.x());
  Serial.print(F(" "));

  Serial.print((float)li_ac.y());
  Serial.print(F(" "));

  Serial.print((float)li_ac.z());
  Serial.print(F(" "));
  Serial.println();

  delay(BNO055_SAMPLERATE_DELAY_MS);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the operation mode from [adafruit_bno055_opmode_t](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BNO055/blob/master/Adafruit_BNO055.h) enum. Use `bno.setMode`.

For modes see section 3.3 in [the datasheet](https://ae-bst.resource.bosch.com/media/_tech/media/datasheets/BST_BNO055_DS000_14.pdf).

The `sensors_event_t` is an union struct so the same memory is accessed with different member names.

Comment: I am not sure which mode to use and I tried setting it to `IMUPlus` and also tried it with `NDOF` but I get the same values for `event.acceleration` and `event.orientation`

Comment: doesn't help much. I referred to the datasheet after you answered and set them in the code's `setup()` and it provides the same output

Comment: as I write the struct is an union. it contains array of 4 floats. this floats are accesible as [0], [1], [2], [3] or over one of `sensors_vec_t` type aliases named `acceleration`, `magnetic`, `orientation` and `gyro`. the first float has additional aliases like `temperature`, `distance`. The event can return only one reading

Comment: read the description of modes "In  the  IMU  mode  the  relative  orientation  of  the  BNO055  in  space  is  calculated  from  the 
accel
erometer and gyroscope data. The calculation is fast (i.e. high output data rate)"

Comment: So I guess with this library I can only use `event.orientation` and obtain the roll, pitch and roll and I have to use the `Adafruit_BNO055` to obtain the linear acc. value separately

Comment: you can read data of the separate sensors or the fusion modes. I don't see how to read data with this library for combined modes like the AMG  mode